# Alphabetizing Results after Order By sort

Tags: sql, list, sorting, sql-order-by

I am trying to write a query that sorts the results of a table to be broken into 3 sections, and I want each section to be in alphabetical order once complete. Here is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM Hospital WHERE Status = 1 Order By HospitalShortName ) 
As Result Order BY CASE HospitalType 
WHEN 'HOS' THEN 1 WHEN 'NH' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END
```

So my intended result would be something like this:

- Hospital A
- Hospital B
- Hospital C
- NursingHome A
- etc.

However, this query returns the list broken into the correct groups but not alphabetical by HospitalShortName. I understand why the above query won't work but I'm lost as to where to go from here. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: _"I understand why the above query won't work"_ just out of curiosity, why?

Comment: I understand that the subquery was alphabetizing successfully, but then being discarded once it was sorted again by HospitalType.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for the subquery. Just add the second column to your outer ORDER BY clause.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Hospital 
    WHERE Status = 1 
    ORDER BY CASE HospitalType 
                 WHEN 'HOS' THEN 1 
                 WHEN 'NH' THEN 2 
                 ELSE 3 
              END, 
              HospitalShortName
```

Comment: Also, not only is there no need, there is no guarantee that the ordering in the sub-query will be maintained in any sense when passed through the outer query.

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware you could do this after using a CASE argument for Order By. Works perfectly.

Comment: My hero. *Exactly* what I was looking for.